# Installation from source fails because of cv_bridge include dir

Tags: ros, build-from-source, cv-bridge, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS from source on Fedora 20 as per http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source.  It fails with:

```
    CMake Error at /home/jfstepha/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'cv_bridge' specifies '//include/opencv' as an include dir, which
  is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/home/jfstepha/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated///include/opencv'
```

The correct path should be "/usr/include/opencv", somehow it seems to be missing the "usr".  Also, it successfully builds 153 packages before this, so it doesn't seem to be a general setup issue.

I'm having a hard time figuring out where this path comes from - can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199279/installation-from-source-fails-because-of-cv_bridge-include-dir/) by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 837 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-10**:
Perhaps this is related: http://answers.ros.org/question/198058/cmake-error-while-building-rpg_svo/ ?

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2014-12-11**:
@ahendrix: It could possibly be somehow related in that it could be an opencv configuration bug, but the root cause of that one had to do with the Nvidia TK1 Jetson board, which I am not using.   It could be the same environmental variable is missing or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS was not getting set properly.  It gets set by this line in /usr/lib64/OpenCVConfig.cmake

```
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include/opencv;${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include")
```

The root cause is probably that OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH is not set properly, but I just changed the line to this:

```
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/opencv;/usr/include")
```

This seemed to work.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case in Jetson Nano, the error happened when I ran `catkin_make clean` for the first time.

The actual path for OpenCV include files was `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2` though `/usr/include/opencv` was expected.

So, after this actual path is written correctly in the `cv_bridgeConfig.cmake` file, the error disappeared.

---

Originally posted by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) with karma: 86 on 2021-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/73818/marcus-forte/) on 2021-04-27**:
The same happened here. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on a Nvidia Jetson platform.

As said above, cv_bridge expects `/usr/include/opencv` but on jetson systems it's under `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2`

The quickest way to solve this, without rewriting config files is to symlink the directories:

`sudo ln -s /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/ /usr/include/opencv`

---

Originally posted by [eeppii](https://answers.ros.org/users/69135/eeppii/) with karma: 116 on 2021-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kidargueta](https://answers.ros.org/users/56703/kidargueta/) on 2021-05-09**:
I think this is the best way to go, as it will fix issues with other scripts trying to find opencv in the future.

**Comment by [mysqo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44877/mysqo/) on 2021-06-04**:
Thanks, this solved my problem when running on NVida Xavier!